# List & documentation for Open Directory properties

Tags: osx-server, user-account, network-user, open-directory, documentation

Anyone know where I can find documentation on the various properties available for directory services on the Mac?

`man dscl` only tells me that I *can* `-create` or `-read` a record. It doesn't tell me *how* to create them; what properties are available and the options can be set on each. I know a few (`RealName`, `UniqueID`, `PrimaryGroupID`, `UserShell`) but where can I find documentation on *all* of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a document from Apple called
["Mac OS X Server
Open Directory Administration
For Version 10.4 or Later"](http://web.archive.org/web/20070315112121/http://images.apple.com/server/pdfs/Open_Directory_v10.4.pdf).

Read Appendix "Mac OS X Directory Data", it contains all what you ask about:

- "Standard Attributes in Group Records" at page 222
- "Standard Attributes in User Records" at page 217

Here is excerpt from the last one:

[image: open directory attributes]

…

You can get **this** document [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20070315112121/http://images.apple.com/server/pdfs/Open_Directory_v10.4.pdf).

---

There are a lot of [**newer documents** on Apple site](https://support.apple.com/manuals/#Open%20Directory%20Administration) (haven't seen them yet). They may be useful to.